# Pattern properties not working as expected in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am struggling to get a simple definition for audio and video. The format should be of the form,

```
   "audio": "These are mp3 artifacts" or 
   "digital": "These are .mp4 or .wav files"
```

I attempted as described in the documentation, using patternProperties with a regex which validates in a regex engine, like this, but it did not work.

```
       {
          "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
          "description": "Definitions common to all most schemas",
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties":false,
          "Definitions": {
             "type": "object",
             "patternProperties": {
             "digital|audio": {"type": "string"}
           },   
            "title": "Definitions"
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
 "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "patternProperties": {
    "^digital$": {
    "type": "string"
     },
    "^audio$": {
     "type": "string"
   }

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "Definitions" object. See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties. This should work:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "patternProperties": {
    "digital|audio": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works against "audio2":"My favourite playlist" which is incorrect

Comment: Check the blue note at the link above: "Regular expressions are not anchored. This means that ... may match anywhere within the property name". You can use ^...$ to avoid this.

Comment: I already posted the above